# Как вывести данные из вложенного объекта в json?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо вывести вложенные данные из массива `json`.

Данные, которые `string` выводятся.

Как вывести данные, которые `object`?

Вот код:

```js
'use strict';
var module_contacts_list = (function() {
  function ajax(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
  }

  function createTemplate() {
    var template = document.createElement('div');
    template.className = 'contact';
    template.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
    return template;
  }
  return {
    loadContacts: function() {
      ajax('http://demo.sibers.com/users', function(data) {
        var contact_list = document.getElementById('contacts_list');
        var template = createTemplate();
        var res = data.reduce(function(acc, contact) {
          var contactElement = template.cloneNode(true);
          contactElement.querySelector('img').src = contact.avatar;
          delete contact.avatar;
          for (var contactProp in contact) {
            if (typeof contact[contactProp] === 'string') {
              var p = document.createElement('p');
              p.innerHTML = contactProp + ": " + contact[contactProp];
              contactElement.appendChild(p);
            }
            if (typeof contact[contactProp] === 'object') {
              for (var sub_contactProp in contact[contactProp]) {
                p.innerHTML = sub_contactProp + ": " + contact[contactProp];
              }
            }
          }
          acc.appendChild(contactElement);
          return acc;
        }, document.createDocumentFragment());
        contact_list.appendChild(res);
      });
    }
  }
})();
module_contacts_list.loadContacts();
```

```css
#contact_list {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.contact {
  clear: both;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-height: 150px;
}
.contact:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.contact p {
  margin: 2px 0;
}
.title-contact-name {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F62459;
}
.contact img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  /*max-height: 100px;
    width:auto;*/
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  background: url('../img/no-avatar.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contacts_list"></div>
```

[Полный код](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/jw75c734/)

Comment: можете использовать `JSON.stringify(contact[contactProp])`

Comment: это в отдельной функции или в отдельном цикле? сейчас у меня двойная проверка условия `if`...

Comment: это вот внутри второго if вместо `": " + contact[contactProp]`

Comment: круть! спасибо!

Comment: @Grundy, оформите ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как объект сложный, то по умолчанию *toString* выведет `[object Object]`, чтобы этого избежать можно использовать `JSON.stringify`

```
if(typeof contact[contactProp] === 'object') {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = contactProp+ ": " + JSON.stringify(contact[contactProp]);
    contactElement.appendChild(p);
}
```